# Count all values that are greater than or less than 20 from a MySQL Database

Tags: php, count, comparison

I need some code to get a count of values that are less than or greater than 20 out of my MySQL DB
It should make a output of how many values there are. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a count initial to zero. Select the table from the mysql and loop through each variable if the variable is greater than 20 then count++. At last take the value of count which will be our expected result.

```
$count=0;
$result=mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM table_name");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if($row['column_name']>20)
{
$count++;
}
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO FU**ING MUCH, haha

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way. 1. mysql functions are deprecated (use mysqli or PDO); 2. one should try to do as maximum filtering on the database side as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever dealt with 'More Like This', but If you need just a query, here it is:

```
SELECT count(*) as less_than_20 FROM my_table WHERE my_column < 20
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) as greater_than_20 FROM my_table WHERE my_column > 20
```

Answer (score 1):

OR

If you want to count all values that are `not 20` then,

```
SELECT count(*) as not_20 FROM my_table WHERE my_column <> 20
```